# $U(n)$ is a regular submanifold of $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: matrices, manifolds, lie-groups, pushforward

I want to show that $U(n)$ is a regular submanifold of $GL(n,\mathbb C)$, for this I figured I use the regular level set theorem. For $U(n)$ is the preimage of the identity $I$ under the map $f:GL(n,\mathbb C)\to GL(n,\mathbb C)$ defined by $A\mapsto A^*A$. So I want to show that the differential of $f$ at $A\in U(n)$ is surjective. For this let $X\in T_AGL(n,\mathbb C)$, so that we identify $X$ with a matrix in $\mathbb C^{n\times n}$. Let $\gamma(t)=A\exp(tA^*X)$, so that $\gamma(0)=A$ and $\gamma'(0)=AA^*X\exp(0\cdot A^*X)=X$. Now we compute the differential:

\begin{align}f_{*,A}X=\frac{d}{dt}\Bigr|_{t=0}\bigr(f(\gamma(t)) \bigr)&=\frac{d}{dt}\Bigr|_{t=0}\Bigr( [\exp(tX^*A)A^*]\cdot[A\exp(tA^*X)]\Bigr)\\
&=X^*AA^*A+A^*AA^*X=X^*A+A^*X.
\end{align}
Here is where I am stuck, I do not know how to prove this is surjective.

Comment: Why don't you just choose $\gamma(t) = A\exp (tX)$?

Comment: @ArcticChar then we would have $\gamma'(0)=AX\neq X$

Comment: okay... it's not a big deal though. You want the sujectivity of the mapping $X\mapsto X^* A + A^*X$, write $Y= A^*X$, you are asking if $Y \mapsto Y^* +Y$ is surjective.

Comment: @ArcticChar Then I think there is another issue, for example if $Z$ is not hermitian, then there is no $Y$ such that $Y^*+Y=Z$ for $Y^*+Y$  is hermitian. This ruins my whole attempt also.

Comment: Yes, because your mapping $A \mapsto A^*A$ maps into the space of hermitian invertible matrices. If you restrict to target  (instead of the whole $GL$), then it might works

Comment: Nice, thanks. The inverse is then $Z\mapsto Z/2$ and we are done. Thank you